# Posting a review on appexchange

Tags: appexchange, isv, app

Some prospects have tried our product. Our product spins a new org since we have an OEM app.Customers who have created a new org would like to review on appexchange. How can they do that if the trial org has expired and they don't have access to any other org?

Answer (score 2):

They can always sign up for a [free developer org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000td6N). I use my developer org to login to the success community. That way my info travels with me, even if I change jobs.